# "Input Not Supported" when connecting 2nd monitor to laptop (HDMI to VGA)

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I'm trying to hook up a second monitor to my laptop as I work from home in this lovely day and age we're living in. My laptop is a relatively new Acer Aspire 5 purchased last fall. Its only available display port is HDMI. The monitor I'm trying to use is an Acer S200HL that's several years old but is the newest one I've got. I have a little HDMI to VGA adapter (pictured below) that I've used successfully a number of times to hook laptops up to projectors, Smartboards, etc. that use VGA connections, though I've never done it with this particular laptop.

[image]

The adapter's specs state that it can support resolutions up to 1920 x 1200 @ 60HZ and 1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz (which is what my laptop is). I tracked down the specs for this monitor and its max resolution is 1600 x 900 @ 60 Hz. It's got both VGA and DVI connections, but I currently only have a VGA cable, so that's what I'm trying to work with.

My issue is that when I get the monitor hooked up to my laptop, I get an "input not supported" message on the monitor's screen. I've looked around here in this forum at some of the other questions along these lines but none of them seem to quite be dealing with my exact predicament. I've tried lowering the resolution on my laptop to 1600 x 900, but that didn't seem to work. One of the answers on a similar question suggested going into Advanced Display Settings and changing the screen refresh rate, so I tried that for the laptop, but 60 Hz is the only option listed (plus the monitor can supposedly handle that anyway). My laptop appears to be recognizing that the monitor is connected (see below), and its refresh rate is shown as 59 Hz. However, when I go in and attempt to change it (50 Hz and 60 Hz are the only other options), I get a message saying the display settings are unable to be changed.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions for something else I can try? I had just really wanted to be able to use two screens, and short of connecting to my TV with a straight up HDMI connection (which doesn't make for an ideal work environment) I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: You said of the older monitor "It's got both VGA and DVI connections"  .  Did you / can you try a DVI to HDMI adapter?

Comment: @John I mean I could, but I'd have to order one. I was hoping to be able to make do with what I have on hand.

Comment: There are lots of these online so, yes, order one and that should work for you.  You would need a DVI connector and wire up to it to make one. That could be messy.

Comment: Hm, okay. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since the above appears to be an answer, I will post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said of the older monitor "It's got both VGA and DVI connections" . You can get a DVI to HDMI adapter to do the conversion for you.

Here is an example:

https://www.primecables.ca/en/p-305019-cab-2029-dvi-d-single-link-male-to-hdmi-female-adapter

You mentioned modifying what you have but that did not work and getting the actual adapter will very likely work better.

Comment: *"You mentioned making one ..."* -- No, the expression *"to make do with what I have"* means "utilize what I already possess rather than modify or acquire additional items."

Comment: I adjusted my phrasing to take your suggestion into account.

Answer (score -1):

> I tracked down the specs for this monitor and its max resolution is 1600 x 900 @ 60 Hz.
>   ...
>   My issue is that when I get the monitor hooked up to my laptop, I get an "input not supported" message on the monitor's screen.

If you're using your laptop at its default resolution (*"1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz"*), then that exceeds the maximum resolution of the Acer S200HL monitor.
So an "*Input not supported*" message is expected.

---

> I've tried lowering the resolution on my laptop to 1600 x 900 ...

That is not a standard VESA resolution.
A *"HDMI to VGA adapter"* (it's actually a converter) may not accept every/any resolution, but typically are constrained to convert a limited number of resolutions.

In fact [this web page](https://reviewfinch.com/p/Ableconn-HDMI2VGAD-HDMI-to-VGA-Adapter-Converter-Dongle-for-Desktop-PC-Notebook-up-to-1920x1200-1920x1080-HDMI-to-VGA-HD15-monitor/60465/) does list the supported resolutions of the Ableconn-HDMI2VGAD, and 1600 x 900 is *not* in that list!

The supported resolutions are: 640x480, 720x480, 720x576, 800x600, 1024x768, 1152x864, 1280x768, 1280x800, 1280x960, 1280x1024, 1360x768, 1360x1024, 1366x768, 1440x900, 1600x1200, 1680x1050, 1920x1080, 1920x1200, 2048x1280, 648p, 720p, 1000p, 1080p.

---

> Does anyone have any suggestions for something else I can try?

Did you try 1280 x 720 @ 60Hz, a resolution common to both VESA and HDTV, a resolution that your laptop should be capable of outputting, a resolution that your *"adapter"* will convert, and a resolution that your monitor will accept?